# How does setup tools determine version of installed packages

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

I am trying to package my application for distribution on PyPi using setuptools. One of our dependencies is pysam and we require version >=8.3, so in our setup.py we have:

```
install_requires = ['pysam>=8.4']
setup(
   ###lots of stuff here
   install_requires=install_requires)
```

When every time setup.py is run, it downloads and installs pysam, and then tells me it failed to find it:

```
Extracting pysam-0.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
pysam 0.2.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysam-0.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
error: The 'pysam>=0.8.4' distribution was not found and is required by umi-tools
```

I was a bit worried by the fact it was talking about pysam 0.2.3, so I checked the version in python

```
>>> import pysam
>>> pysam.__version__
'0.9.1.4'
```

So pysam 0.9.1.4 is being installed. My questions are:

1. How does setup tools determine if a requirement has been met, and could it be thinking pysam 0.2.3 is installed even though 0.9 is.
2. What else could be going on such that setuptools thinks pysam isn't install when it is?

Comment: How are you building the package and installing it ?

Comment: We'll eventually create an egg using setuptools, but at the moment just as source while we get it right.